# PhoneGap / Cordova: iPhone notch is bleeding into the App

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap

I built an Cordova app which is simply starting the InAppBrowser to show a web application. On the iPhone XR the app has a black border on the top and button to not be covered by the iPhones' notch. Everything works as expected. Now I wanted to exchange the splash screen to show my own startup screen. I added my own splash screen information in the config.xml:

```
<platform name="ios">
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@2x~universal~anyany.png" />
    <splash src="res/screen/ios/Default@3x~universal~anyany.png" />
</platform>
```

After adding this information I executed:

```
cordova platform remove ios
cordova platform add ios
cordova build ios
```

Then I start Xcode and run the simulation on an iPhone XR. The new splash screen is displayed correctly, but the black borders on top and bottom of the app are not shown anymore. Instead the notch somehow bleeds into the app, the sticky menu bar of the web page is moved below the notch, but above the menu you can still see the website content in the background.

Why is changing the splash screen completely changing the apps layout?

In my webpage I already added the viewport header:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,viewport-fit=contain">
```

**Expected behavior (no custom splash screen):**
[image: Expected behavior (no custom splash screen)]
**After adding custom splash screen:**
[image: After adding custom s]

Answer (score 3):

After some more research I found out:

The "black bars" that are shown are a fallback when no matching splash screen images are found. So when I added the correct splash screens the app was rendered correctly, using the full height of the screen. Whether the sticky menu is shown on the very top of the screen (covered partially by the notch) or below the notch with the website content partially showing above can be configured by adding this meta tag to the website:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="viewport-fit=cover" />
```

Where "cover" would let the notch cover the content and "contain" would move the content below the notch.

For this meta tag to apply you have to activate this functionality in your cordova config.xml:

```
<preference name="EnableViewportScale" value="true" />
```

To avoid that the website content is shown in the background of the status bar, there are plugins for cordova like "cordova-plugin-statusbar" that should add functionalities to change the status bar behavior. Unfortunately I did not find a working plugin yet, especially working with iOS 12.